# Is it possible to use cloudformation to setup local dynamodb tables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an app which uses dynamodb and cloud formation to setup the tables. When using the local runner is it possable to reuse the cloudformation template to setup tables on the local dynamodb?

Comment: I guess it's safe to say no

Comment: I was thinking so, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for this too and decided to do it myself,

I'ts basically a docker image with dynamodb-local included +
minimal ui for dynamodb and yaml/json upload

It does not process !Ref, !GetAtt etc. yet

[docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/awspilotcom/dynamodb-ui) and [demo](https://awspilot.github.io/dynamodb-oop/pages/ui-demo/)

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this and created this: https://github.com/npocmaka/cloudformation-to-local-dynamo

As local dynamo uses java to wrap sql-lite I've decided that I prefer to start a java process with in-memory dynamo instead of a running a docker image. Though if want to use with other language you can use the shell scripts (in case you have installed java and maven) and get the connection url from the output.

I've tested with cloudformation yaml templates. It does not understand the references, scripts and etc. Just the basic structure of the template.